# How to add to an decoded Json Array from the Database specific selected Values

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, crud

I am working on a movie WebApp. The User selects Movies and it gets added to the database. the column `movie_list` is a JSON because

I want that every time a User add a movie it gets added to the Array and if its already in it I want that it doesn't get added to the array

The problem is instead of adding it to the existing array it will sometime overwrite the Array, just add a nested Array or just create a custom key `(0,1,2,3)`.

I tried to function like

```
  array_merge and array_add

  // It does overwrite it
  array['checkedMovie'] = 3
```

Also thought about for each, but sadly dont know how to realize it.

My Brain is squeezed up.

```
public function update(Request $request, TrackMovie $trackMovie)
    {

      $currentCheckedMoviesArray = DB::table('track_movies')->where('user_id', $trackMovie->user_id)->get('checkedMovie');


      $currentCheckedMoviesArray = json_decode($currentCheckedMoviesArray, true)[0];

      $newarraychecked=array_add($currentCheckedMoviesArray,$currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'], $trackMovie->checkedMovie);



      return dd($newarraychecked);

      $current_length = DB::table('track_movies')->where('user_id', $trackMovie>user_id)->value('lengthOfMovie');
      DB::table('track_movies')->where('user_id', $trackMovie->user_id)->update([
        'lengthOfMovie' => $current_length + $trackMovie->lengthOfMovie,
'checkedMovie' => $newarraychecked;
      ]);
        return dd(TrackMovie::all());
    }
```

To make it a bit clearly I edited this because I think its because of my formatting.

```
$currentCheckedMoviesArray = json_decode($currentCheckedMoviesArray, true)[0];
// DD Result
array:1 [▼
  "checkedMovie" => "["1", "2"]"
]

$trackMovie->checkedMovie
//DD Result
array:2 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "4"
]

$newarraychecked=Arr::collapse($currentCheckedMoviesArray, $trackMovie->checkedMovie);
//DD Result
    []
```

Actual Result:

```
This is the result what I get on the above code
array:1 [▼
  "checkedMovie" => "["1", "2"]"
]

There some more because I tested many things

array:1 [▼
  "checkedMovie" => "["1", "2"]"
   1             => "2"
   2             => "4"

]
```

Expected Result:

```
The User is checking some movies.
// He already has some movies
checkedMovie = ["1","2","3"]

Now the Application Checks if it already existed the movie in the Database. 
If it does not contain in the database I want to add it. User selects Movie ID (5,6)
checkedMovie = ["1","2","3","5","6"]

After that, it will overwrite the Database column value
```

If I have forgotten something to add up to the question, please comment it so I can edit the question!

Comment: Try using `array_collapse` instead of `array_add`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Awkwardly its return me an empty array instead of adding. I edit and show what I get by every variable maybe it is not clear described by me.

Comment: `$newarraychecked=array_map("array_merge",$currentCheckedMoviesArray,$currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'], $trackMovie->checkedMovie);`

Answer (score 0):

You can just push the new values to the array and then use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to filter out the duplicates

Example:

```
public function update(Request $request, TrackMovie $trackMovie)
    {
      //Get Current Array from DB
      $currentCheckedMoviesArray = DB::table('track_movies')->where('user_id', $trackMovie->user_id)->get('checkedMovie');
      $currentCheckedMoviesArray = json_decode($currentCheckedMoviesArray, true)[0];

      //Decode JSON array
      $currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'] = json_decode($currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'])

      //Push the new Movie to the array
      $currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'][] = $trackMovie->checkedMovie;

      //Remove duplicates from the array
      $newarraychecked = array_unique($currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie']);

      ....
    }
```

Comment: It does overwrite it. So like every new Number which get added overwrite the existing database entries

Comment: Is $currentCheckedMoviesArray a single dimensional array?

Comment: Collection {#469 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#498 ▼
      +"checkedMovie": "["1", "2"]"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: This is the full array output i was not sure if it is single Array

Comment: print_r($currentCheckedMoviesArray) after decoding it, what’s the result?

Comment: Array ( [checkedMovie] => ["1", "2"] )

Comment: @TobiasDex So add the movies to `$currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'][]`

See Updated answer

Comment: I tried this approach but I think my Array is just bad. If I do your code I get: [] operator not supported for strings / Fatal Exception

Comment: So I guess ["1", "2"] is not an array, its just a string

Comment: You can try to decode it, so add `$currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'] = json_decode($currentCheckedMoviesArray['checkedMovie'])`

See updated Answer

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I was trying to get to you. I tryed the code and I get everytime a error . and Arrays are confusing me :( . I get now Undefined index: checkedMovie

Comment: The Output of the array I get is like array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]

Comment: I don’t see any “checkedDrink” in your code, which line is giving you this error?

Comment: I mean checkedMovie

Comment: I must be undercover. it is the column name of an type json but in laravel i save it as array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194834/discussion-between-moishe-schwartz-and-tobiasdex).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
$checkedMovie=array(1,2,3);  
$selectedMovie=array(3,4,5,6);
$checkedMovie=array_unique(array_merge($checkedMovie,$selectedMovie));
```